# SQL Server referencing a foreign key to a non-primary key column

Tags: sql-server, database

Recently we ran into the situation as following:

We are designing a database and predicting that data will grow significantly to millions records within 6 months. And we want each row should have a Guid as a Unique ID which allows us move data to OLAP/Archive databases later, after many arguments on Identity and Guid key, we came up with Guid as the Unique ID. However, Guid as a Primary Key is always a bad idea, therefore we have the primary key of the table is a Identity column. The design looks like below

**Users**:

```
| Id (PK, Identity)                                                 |
| UserId (Guid, Unique-constraint, non-clustered index)             |  
| Name                                                              |
| Email                                                             |
| ...                                                               |
```

**Notes**:

```
| Id (PK, Identity)                                                 |
| NoteId (Guid, Unique-constraint, non-clustered index)             |
| UserId (Guid, Foreign Key to Users(UserId)                        |
| Title                                                             |
| Text                                                              |
| ...                                                               |
```

When moving data to archive we don't need to care about the identity key anymore.

Is there any problem about this design ? How about the performance ? Please give me advice, thanks.

Comment: This should be ok. Performance might be better if the foreign key was refering to Users.Id (and you could always transform it to a reference to Users.UserId in your archive) but it wouldn't be significant.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't have the GUID as a primary key, you'll still be using it for the joins, making more work for the server.

Is there a reason you're not using Users.Id as the FK target?

```
UserId (INT, Foreign Key to Users(Id)
```

Bear in mind that you'd also be wanting to index the above column, so your way you still end up with two GUID indexes on the table, likely fragmented as I bet the programmers are making random GUIDs in the app tier, not you making NEWSEQUENTIALID() in the DB?

Comment: The reason for not referencing to Users(Id) is that, I experienced a Identity Key shifting in replication with MySQL before  and now really afraid of that situation, fixing the data was a nightmare. And with MS SQL server we got key shifting again on a recent project, luckily we detected it early. The Guid could be provided at Databse Server or Business Layer, we have not decided.

Comment: @KaneNguyen If you're wondering where to make the GUID, do look into NEWSEQUENTIALID (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) it's from 2005 upwards and really cuts down on GUID index fragmentation - Which would alleviate some of the problems. I'd be interested in how the key-shifting occurred - I've never seen it myself.

Comment: AFAIK, NEWSEQUENTIALID will restart at a different segment after restarting the server. There is no guaranty that the new segment will be behind the previous one, but I agree that it will give better performance than NEWID

Comment: While that may be true, surely it's still preferable to a truly random value on each insert :)